# O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?

Tags: java

Eu estava vendo alguns métodos das classes do pacote `javax` e alguns deles possuem assinatura semelhantes a esta:

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params){}
```

O que significa esse " **`...`** " ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

O que você tem no exemplo mencionado é a definição de que o parâmetro `params` vai receber os argumentos em um *array de Strings*, a partir do Java 5.0+ (esta definição é conhecida como "varargs").

Em outras palavras, você pode ter um número variável de argumentos na chamada da função à partir de onde foi especificado o `...`.

Esta sintaxe pode ser usada mesclada com parâmetros "normais":

```
void teste( String a, Integer... b ) {
    //...
}

teste( "a" );        //  a  recebe "a", b  fica vazio
teste( "a", 1, 2 );  //  a  recebe "a", b  recebe { 1, 2 }
```

E ainda, se quiser usar tipos variados nos argumentos:

```
void teste( String a, Object... b ) {
    //...
}

teste( "a", 1, "x", 7 );  //  a  recebe "a", b  recebe { 1, "x", 7 }
```

Note que, neste caso, você está perdendo a checagem em tempo de compilação em `b` pelo fato de o objeto aceitar tipos diferentes nos argumentos, e usualmente deve fazer esta checagem em *runtime* para sanitizar os valores e poder usá-los com tranquilidade.

Comment: Lembrando que também pode ser chamada de elipse.

Comment: isso é a mesma coisa que String[] b?

Comment: @Skywalker essencialmente sim. Mas aí não tem o açúcar sintático na chamada.

Answer (score 14):

Denominado por `varargs`, é uma funcionalidade/capacidade permite que  um método receber  múltiplos ou nenhum argumento do mesmo tipo.

O `... doInBackground(String... params)` significa que este método pode receber nenhum parâmetro ou vários do tipo `String`.

Mais detalhes:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs

Answer (score 9):

> **Nota**: essa resposta inicialmente eu dei em uma pergunta que depois foi identificada como copia desta pergunta daqui. Como as respostas dadas nesta pergunta não exemplificam como usar o varargs (apenas como chamar), então acho que esta resposta complementa às do @Bacco e do @Cold.

O `...` é chamado de ellipsis ou varargs, dentro de `teste`, `obj` terá o mesmo comportamento que um vetor. Por exemplo:

```
public void teste(Object... obj) {
    for (int I = 0; I < obj.length; i++)  {
      Object atual = obj[i];
      System.out.println(i + "-esimo elemento: " + atual);
  }
}
```

Para chamar `teste`, entretanto, você não precisa instanciar um vetor. Você poderia fazer assim:

```
teste("primeiro parâmetro", Integer.valueOf(1), null, BigDecimal.TEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

A notação `...` (três pontos, que no português é conhecido como "reticências") é conhecida no Java como **varargs**. Ele permite que um método aceite um número indefinido de parâmetros de determinado tipo.

No seu caso:

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params){}
```

Este método aceita uma quantidade indefinida de parâmetros do tipo `String`.

Ao receber este `params` no seu método, você pode ler o seu conteúdo tratando o `params` **como um array qualquer**. Assim, chamando o método da seguinte maneira:

```
doInBackground("Joao", "Pedro", "Paulo");
```

Teremos:

```
protected void doInBackground(String... params){
    if (params.length > 0) {
         String paramZero = params[0];
         System.out.println(paramZero); // imprimirá 'João'
    }
}
```

Apesar da sua flexibilidade, o varargs tem algumas limitações e riscos:

- Só **é permitido um varargs** por método;
- A variável varargs **deve ser o último parâmetro** do método;
- Pode criar soluções estranhas e pouco intuitivas, [como esta do Slf4J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374166/2387977), onde ele aceita um varargs de `Object` para as variáveis da mensagem de log, porém ele verifica, internamente, se o último parâmetro dentro do varargs é algum tipo de exception, para fazer o log da mesma;
- Situações de *overload* envolvendo varargs [podem passar desapercebidas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295730/2387977) no código e causar situações inesperadas.