# Como posso associar 3 autores a apenas um livro?

Tags: java, groovy

```
package crud

class Start {
  static main(args) {
    Autor autor = new Autor()
    autor.nome = "Aline Gonzaga"
    autor.email ='aline2@yahoo.com.br'
    autor.cpf =' 78544378654'


    Livro livro = new Livro(autor)
    livro.nome='Java: '
    livro.descricao= 'java'
    livro.valor= 378.99
    //livro.isbn= "8975849-54-5665-34-3-324-656-32-34-123"

    //livro.autor = autor


    livro.mostrarDetalhes()

    Ebook ebook = new Ebook()

    Autor outroAutor = new Autor()
    outroAutor.cpf ='754.548.545-34'
    outroAutor.email='li@email.com'
    outroAutor.nome='Jesus Cristo'

    Livro outroLivro = new Livro(outroAutor)
    outroLivro.descricao =' Como fazer o bem ao próximo?'
    outroLivro.isbn = ' 8754868596845986946'
  //    outroLivro.nome =' Fazendo o que é agradável a Deus'
    outroLivro.valor = 467.99
  //    outroLivro.autor = outroAutor
    outroLivro.mostrarDetalhes()


  }
}
```

package crud

class Livro {

```
String nome
String descricao
double valor
String isbn
Autor autor

void mostrarDetalhes() {
    println "mostrando detalhes do livro: "
    println "Nome: " + nome
    println "Descrição: " + descricao
    println "ISBN " + isbn
    println "Valor: "+ valor
    autor.mostrarDetalhes()
    println "-----------------------------"
}
    public  Livro(Autor autor) {
    this()
    this.autor = autor
    }

    public Livro(){
        this.isbn = "0000-0000000-000000-000000-00"
        this.nome = " "
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se você está familiarizada com [**Collections**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) e [**Generics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), mas esta aí uma forma de solucionar o problema.

Ao invés da sua classe `Livro` possuir um atributo de tipo `Autor`, você pode ter uma `List<Autor>` que representa uma lista de autores do respectivo livro.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Livro {

    List<Autor> listaDeAutores = new ArrayList<>();
    // Outros atributos do livro...

    Livro(Autor autor){
        listaDeAutores.add(autor);
    }

    Livro (Autor...autores){
        listaDeAutores.addAll(Arrays.asList(autores));
    }

    // Métodos...
}
```

Dessa forma você pode criar um novo livro contendo um autor. Por exemplo:

```
Autor autor = // ...
Livro livro = new Livro(autor);
```

Ou, com vários autores. Por exemplo:

```
Autor autor = // ...
Autor segundoAutor = // ...
Autor terceiroAutor = // ...

Livro livro = new Livro(autor, segundoAutor, terceiroAutor);
```

Para exibir a lista de autores você pode recuperar a lista contida no atributo `listaDeAutores` e fazer um loop para percorrê-la:

```
List<Autor> autoresDoLivro = livro.listaDeAutores;

for(Autor autor : autoresDoLivro){
   System.out.println("Nome: " + autor.nome);
}
```

---

<sub>Não é relacionado ao que foi perguntado, mas considere encapsular os atributos e métodos dos seus objetos.
[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/4808) possui algumas explicações.</sub>

Comment: Gostei da resposta! Mas essa parte não entendi:------------------------------Livro (Autor...autores){
        listaDeAutores.addAll(Arrays.asList(autores));
    }

Comment: Aline, a grosso modo, [**Arrays#asList()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) transforma um array em uma *collection*. No construtor de `Livro`, os autores são passados por [***varargs***](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/4808), como se fosse `Autor[] autores`. Então (de novo, a grosso modo) o array de `Autor` acaba virando uma *collection* autores.

Comment: Isto é Groovy e não Java, além do código não ser idiomático para Groovy, a observação final não faz sentido em Groovy, já está encapsulado. Listas em Groovy possui sintaxe própria na linguagem: http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Lists Funciona normal, mas não é o estilo mais usado.

Comment: Depois que ela postou outra pergunta sobre Groovy eu vi mesmo, a principio pensei que fosse Java.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi direito você poderia fazer um construtror na classe Livro que recebe 3 argumentos onde cada um seria um autor. Isso se quiser sempre associar 1 autor ou 3 autores a um livro. Se prefere fazer essa associação de forma dinâmica(variando de 1 a x autores por livro), acredito que uma solução seria usando array de x posições onde cada posição guarda um autor. Ai só passar este array como argumento no construtor.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer esse array?

Comment: To sem IDE no momento, mas daqui a pouco edito a resposta com o código, pode colocar o código da classe Livro?