# O que significa o termo "String... string" em Java?

Tags: java, string, parâmetros, return

O que significa o termo `String... string` em Java? E como elaborar um método que retorne uma `String...` como exemplo:

```
public String... getStrings(){
     return String... s;)
}
```

Eu sei que não é dessa forma, mas queria saber como faz para que eu possa passar como parâmetro num método assim:

```
public void setStrings(String... s){
      //codigo
}
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/3117)

Comment: @Math isso responde o que significa, mas o principal que eu quero saber é como elaborar um método que me retorne isso para eu passar como parametro no outro método, visto que ele nao aceita como parametro uma `String[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso é chamado de [*varargs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

Essa é a forma de indicar que o último parâmetro é na verdade um *array* do tipo mencionado. Então os argumentos na chamada do método podem ter uma quantidade variável. Ou seja, após os argumentos fixos e obrigatórios, podem contar de zero à "infinitos" argumentos desde que seja do tipo declarado.

Quando for acessar `s` (no seu exemplo) lembre-se que essa variável é um *array* e deve acessá-lo desta forma.

Entenda a [diferença entre parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Mais detalhes em [O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/101)

O retorno não é possível dessa forma, ele só serve para parâmetros. Nem tem sentido ter algo assim, afinal isso é um açúcar sintático. Se precisa retornar vários itens tem que usar um *array* ou outra coleção de dados normal, como um `ArrayList` ou mesmo uma classe previamente definida.

```
public String[] getStrings() {
     return new String[] {"x", "y"};
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/VarArgs.java).