# Como criar um método com parâmetros opcionais em Java puro?

Tags: java, método, parâmetros, argumento

Como crio um método que não necessite inserir todos os parâmetros?

Ex. Existe um método que pede 5 parâmetros. Mas eu pretendo usar somente 2.

Comment: Ou é isso que é sugerido na duplicata, ou usando sobrecarga no mesmo método com menos parametros. A resposta da duplicata acredito que responde essa pergunta

Comment: você pode sobrecarregar um metodo ou passar apenas um parametro como array e nesse array ter os argumentos.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Algumas linguagens permitem o uso de [**argumentos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) opcionais (parâmetros nunca podem ser opcionais). Java não é uma delas.

Existe a possibilidade de criar diversos métodos sobrecarregados com um conjunto de parâmetros diferentes. Isso pode ser uma maluquice porque precisará, no extremo, mais de 20 métodos nesse caso para atender todas possibilidades (claro que é possível fazer só uma certa quantidade, eventualmente pode fazer 5 ou até menos).

Outra possibilidade é usar [argumentos variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119541/101) ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111034/101)). Isso é bem diferente de argumentos opcionais, mas pode ser usado para simular, em situações bem específicas. O normal é usar esse recurso apenas para sequências de dados, até porque não dá para controlar a quantidade de argumentos a serem passados. Para aceitar de tipos diferentes, terá que declarar um tipo `Object` que não é o ideal, e mesmo assim nem todos tipos serão aceitos (os primitivos não são `Object`, então pode um `Integer`, mas não um `int`). Ou seja, não vai dar muito certo.

Em resumo, fazer direito não dá até que a linguagem ofereça uma outra alternativa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O Varargs não seria uma alternativa também?

Comment: @diegofm está escrito na resposta, é uma alternativa, mas não muito boa.

Comment: E se criar uma classe Wrapper?

Comment: @Matheus não sei como isso poderia ajudar, mas mesmo que ajude, seria muita complicação para pouca ajuda, possivelmente deturpando o intuito.

Answer (score 2):

Como descrito na resposta do Maniero não tem como fazer isso em Java. Uma alternativa seria a seguinte:

Método original:

```
void metodo(int arg1, String arg2, int arg3, String arg4, String arg5) {
}
```

Você pode fazer isso aqui:

```
void metodo(int arg1, String arg2) {
    metodo(arg1, arg2, 0, "default2", "default3");
}
```

Você vai sobrecarregar o método original colocando somente dois parâmetros. Então no novo método criado você irá chamar o método original. Dessa forma, você vai poder passar para o método original os valores *default* que você deseja, juntamente com os valores passados por parâmetro no novo método.

Você poderá chamar o método assim:

```
metodo(100, "teste");
```

O método sobrecarregado chamará o método original passando os valores *default*.

Comment: Como eu chamo esse método?

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos editei a resposta. Veja se agora ficou melhor.