# Atribuir valor à variável na declaração do método

Tags: java

É possível atribuir o valor default de uma variável dentro da declaração do método, igual ocorre no `PHP`? Se sim, como?

Ex: quero que a função teste, quando chamada, se não for passado nenhum parâmetro, tenha o valor de b `false` e `true` caso seja chamada `this.teste(true);`

```
public function teste(Boolean b = false){

}
```

Comment: Acredito que o mais próximo que você vai conseguir é usando [**varargs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) como explicado [neste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119546/28595) e [neste aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46175/28595) pois java não permite que você não passe nada a um método que espere algum parâmetro.

Comment: No caso, eu gostaria de deixar um valor atribuído a ela caso não fosse passado

Comment: Então, não é possível isso em java. Se um método espera um parametro, ele obrigatoriamente deve ser passado, ou você precisa escrever um novo método com a assinatura sem passagem de parametros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, no java não tem como atribuir um valor padrão dessa forma.

Agora você pode obter esse comportamento de "valor padrão" em um método de outras formas.
Exemplo:

```
public void teste(Boolean b){
      if(b == null){
             b = false;}
```

Ou caso o interesse seja simplesmente tornar o parametro não obrigatorio, você pode usar sobrecarga criando dois metodos:

```
public void teste(){
     teste(false);
}



public void teste(Bollean b){}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Porém, no primeiro exemplo, não é possível chamar o método teste() sem passar nenhum valor

Comment: Então, como eu não sabia exatamente o que você queria, dei os dois exemplos.

Comment: Ah sim, certo. Isso resolve meu problema. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Como está usando um objeto como parâmetro, a classe `Optional` pode ser útil para checar se o valor é nulo (e se for, usar um "valor padrão"):

```
public void teste(Boolean b){
  b = Optional.ofNullable(b).orElse(false);

  System.out.println("Valor de 'b': " + b);
}
```

```
teste(true);  // Valor de 'b': true
teste(false); // Valor de 'b': false
teste(null);  // Valor de 'b': false
```

Ou então, como mencionado nos comentários, fazer uso de *varargs*:

```
public static void teste(Boolean... b){
   boolean value = b.length > 0 ? b[0] : false;
   System.out.println("Valor de 'b': " + value);
}
```

```
teste(true);  // Valor de 'b': true
teste(false); // Valor de 'b': false
teste();      // Valor de 'b': false
```

Answer (score 1):

Se está procurando um parâmetro opcional, use sobrecarga de métodos.

```
public void teste() {
    teste(false);
}

public void teste(boolean b) {
    //executa ação aqui
}
```

Isto funciona para métodos simples. Não recomendaria usar mais de duas ou três versões do mesmo método e só quando não houver mais de dois ou três parâmetros envolvidos, pois a sobrecarga pode levar a situações bizarras e confusão na hora de passar os parâmetros.

Caso você tenha métodos com vários parâmetros, passe um objeto como parâmetro implementando o *builder pattern*.

Por exemplo, ao invés de fazer assim:

```
void fazerPizza(boolean mussarela, boolean oregano, boolean calabreza, boolean tomate, String nome) {
    //...
}

...  

fazerPizza(true, false, true, false, "Calabreza");
```

Poderia ficar assim:

```
void fazerPizza(PizzaBuilder b) {
    //...
}

fazerPizza(new PizzaBuilder("Calabreza")
    .mussarela()
    .calabreza());
```

Com esse padrão, você consegue auto-completar os parâmetros possíveis sem se confundir, omitir aquilo que não quiser e ainda deixar valores padrão no objeto `PizzaBuilder` caso queira.

Leia mais em [*Construindo objetos de forma inteligente: Builder Pattern e Fluent Interfaces*](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/).