# Passagem de vários parâmetros como um Array

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu tenho um método que recebe uma quantidade desconhecida de parâmetros como um Array, dessa forma:

```
public void enviarCampos(String funcao, String... campos) {
  // Ação do método
}
```

Para chamar esse método faço:

```
enviarCampos("CADASTRAR", "nome", "dataNascimento", "sexo", "rg", "cpf");
```

O problema é que eu não sei quais vão ser esses parâmetros, eles vão depender de varias condições, portanto não tenho como colocar fixo. Coloquei esses parâmetros em um `ArrayList`, para que eu possa manipular a lista de parâmetros, e tentei fazer um *cast* para chamar o método, mas não funcionou:

```
ArrayList<String> listaCampos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("nome", "dataNascimento", "sexo", "rg", "cpf"));
enviarCampos("CADASTRAR", (String[]) listaCampos.toArray());
```

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46174/o-que-significam-as-retic%C3%AAncias-nos-par%C3%A2metros-de-um-m%C3%A9todo)

Comment: Porque não pode tipar os dados no método?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método [toArray(T[] arr)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

```
ArrayList<String> listaCampos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("nome", "dataNascimento", "sexo", "rg", "cpf"));
enviarCampos("CADASTRAR", listaCampos.toArray(new String[listaCampos.size()]));
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema!