# Como setar valores de um atributo array?

Tags: java, array

Eu tenho uma classe java que representa uma entidade *lanche*,segue abaixo a classe:

```
public class Lanche {
    private String nome;
    private int id;
    private double preco;
    private String[] ingredientes;
/*getters setters */
}
```

Abaixo segue a classe de teste na qual eu estou instanciando um objeto do tipo lanche e setando os atributos:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lanche lanche = new Lanche();
        lanche.setId(001);
        lanche.setNome("X-salada");
        lanche.setPreco(5.00);
        lanche.setIngredientes("Hamburguer","Queijo","Salada");
    }
}
```

Como setar corretamente o atributo ingredientes, que é uma array de strings? Pois da forma que eu exemplifiquei esta dando o seguinte erro:

> The method setIngredientes(String[]) in the type Lanche is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo erro, o método espera um array de strings e não 3 strings separadas como parâmetro. Há várias formas de corrigir mas acredito que a abaixo seja a menos drástica:

```
lanche.setIngredientes(new String[]{"Hamburguer","Queijo","Salada"});
```

Ou pode ser feito também utilizando *varargs*, onde você deve alterar a assinatura do seu método conforme abaixo:

```
public void setIngredientes(String... ingredientes){
    //... codigo do método
}
```

e continuar passando os argumentos da mesma forma:

```
lanche.setIngredientes("Hamburguer","Queijo","Salada");
```

A variável `ingredientes` continua sendo um array, como pode ser visto neste teste no ideone: https://ideone.com/4mBvs6

Para aprender mais sobre *varargs*, veja os links abaixo, retirados aqui mesmo do site:

- [O que significam as reticências nos parâmetros de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46174/28595)
- [Passagem de argumentos opcionais em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119541/28595)

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado.